# How do I use screencapture for capturing floating windows?

Tags: applescript, screen-capture, skype

I am trying to automate the periodic capture of a floating window. Specifically, of the floating 'Current Call' window which is used by Skype when the main window is off-screen.

By googling, I found out that all I need is a window id to pass to screencapture:

```
screencapture -l<win_id> <output_file>
```

The problem is that I haven't found a way to get the window id for "Current Call". Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Skype" to id of first window whose floating is true'
20:61: execution error: Skype got an error: Can’t get window 1 whose floating = true. Invalid index. (-1719)
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Skype" to id of first window whose name is "Current Call"'
20:67: execution error: Skype got an error: Can’t get window 1 whose name = "Current Call". Invalid index. (-1719)
```

Does anyone know how to get the window id for the "Current Call" window?

Or, alternatively, does anyone know if I can get this screenshot in some other way? (e.g. run `screencapture` with other arguments, or use some other tool for capturing the screenshot)

---

**Update**

I have also tried the following:

```
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Skype" to id of window 0'
-1
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Skype" to id of window 1'
-1
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Skype" to id of window 2'
84
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Skype" to id of window 3'
20:22: execution error: Skype got an error: Can’t get window 3. Invalid index. (-1719)
```

Window with id 84 is the main skype window. So, I'm a bit puzzled here. What is `-1` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a command line utility that wraps over `screencapture` and the Quartz windowing library.

Grab it here: https://github.com/thismachinechills/pyscreencapture

Use it like this:

```
./screencapture.py Skype -t Current Call -w all_windows above_window
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Skype" to id of first window whose name = ""
```

Comment: Did you try this? It returns some window id but the screen capture for it gives me this image, which I have no idea what is: http://i.imgur.com/3KDh1rA.png

Comment: I didn't try the screen capture. I just found the new window id.

Comment: I tried again, with the same skype call running. This time I got `Invalid index. (-1719)`. Weird...